# C# Invalid Cast exception (I don't know where is the error)

Tags: c#, out

So, i made this method to detect if there's anything in front of the player when a button is pressed, the problem is, even tough the same method without the out parameter (it returns whoever is in front of the player) seems to work, this one throws an invalid cast exception, even though i researched i still don't know what's the problem here.

The problematic function code:

```
public bool isThereAnythingThere(Rectangle rec, out NPC other) {
    bool tmp = false;
    other = null;

    foreach (NPC npc in gol)
    {
        if (npc.collider.Intersects(rec))
        {
            tmp = true;
            other = npc;
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Player function that triggers it:

```
void Action1()
{
    NPC go = null;

    switch (facingDirection) {
        case Direction.Up: if (!game.isThereAnythingThere(UpRectangle), out go) ;
            break;
        case Direction.Down: if (!game.isThereAnythingThere(DownRectangle), out go) ;
            break;
        case Direction.Left: if (!game.isThereAnythingThere(LeftRectangle), out go) ;
            break;
        case Direction.Right: if (!game.isThereAnythingThere(RightRectangle), out go) ;
            break;
        } //Now go equals the object in the direction where facing, if theres no object, is null

        if (go != null)
            game.textBox.AddText(go.GetDialogue());
    }
}
```

PS: `gol` is a list of all `GameObject`s in my game;
`GameObject` is a class of which both `Player` and `NPC` inherit from.

Comment: What type is `gol`? If it's not an enumerable of `NPC` that `foreach` will cause that type of exception.

Comment: When you debug and advance line by line, which line throws the error?

Comment: The StackTrace of the exception should give you the information you need.  If not, update your code to be a complete minimal program required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can't give us an exception without the stacktrace as well as you can't give us CastException without the entire class declaration structure (class full definitions)

Comment: What is the exact type of `gol`? I suspect it's a non-generic list (e.g. ArrayList), so it might contain something that isn't a `NPC`

Comment: gol is a List<GameObject> where GameObject is a base class i use for both Player and NPC.
Probably the problem is in that but i haven't managed this type of things before so i'm not exactly sure.

Comment: The error is produced in the foreach(NPC npc) line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're iterating through a list that might contain something that is not an `NPC` and telling the `foreach` to try to cast everything to `NPC`.

The easiest fix would be to use Linq `OfType<T>` to filter the list by type:

```
foreach (NPC npc in gol.OfType<NPC>())
```